# Hierarchy Custom Setting .getInstance() Id

Tags: apex, customsetting

What's the best way to get the Id of the custom setting referenced in `MyCustomSetting__c.getInstance()` for a hierarchical custom setting?

I'm trying to update your current instance of a custom setting via apex, but can't seem to get the Id (therefore no update possible) from `.getInstance().Id`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few things to take into consideration:

1. Are you accessing from a test method - If so you must insert a custom setting first
2. Is there a record for the Specified "Instance" for the current context user?

If no custom setting for the current user is defined then it returns a new custom setting and the ID will be blank. Otherwise the getInstance() should return the ID:

```
CustomSettingExample__c cs = CustomSettingExample__c.getInstance();

//cd.id - should NOT be null if a custom setting exists for the current context user.
```

See [Custom Settings Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm):

> If no custom setting data is defined for the user, this method returns
>   a new custom setting object. The new custom setting object contains an
>   ID set to null and merged fields from higher in the hierarchy. You can
>   add this new custom setting record for the user by using insert or
>   upsert. If no custom setting data is defined in the hierarchy, the
>   returned custom setting has empty fields, except for the SetupOwnerId
>   field which contains the user ID.

**If you need more detailed answer then you may be better served by posting your code so we can tell if it is a problem with your code or not.**

Comment: That's what was missing.  I had a profile setting configured, but not a user setting.

Comment: @NathanWilliams Note that if you use CustomSettingExample__c.getOrgDefaults() you *will* get an ID that you can use to update that custom setting later.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving my use case.

I am building out `@testSetup` functionality in my org to reduce test runtimes (since I batch all test classes to run daily), and utilize a `UtilTest` class to house my test data creation methods as well as some stock variables (a generic Account `acc` that can be used anywhere easily without having to recreate over and over again).  However, `@testSetup` appears to not maintain it's instantiation when transitioning from `@testSetup` to `@isTest`.

```
@isTest
public with sharing class UtilTest {

    public static Account buildAccount() {
        return new Account(
            Name = 'Test Account',
            RecordTypeId = System.Label.RecordTypeIdAccountStandard
        );
    }

    public static Account acc {
        get {
            if (acc == null) {
                if (UtilCustomSettings.TestSettings.Account__c == null) {
                    acc = buildAccount();
                    insert acc;
                    UtilCustomSettings.updateTestSettings('Account__c', acc.Id);
                } else {
                    acc = new Account(Id = UtilCustomSettings.TestSettings.Account__c);
                }
            }
            return acc;
        }
    }

}
```

I reference `UtilCustomSettings.TestSettings` everywhere in my org when I need to access `TestSettings__c`.  When I need to update the running user's most applicable instance, I call `UtilCustomSettings.updateTestSettings()` which references `setTestSettingsId()` to traverse up the chain (check for me first, then my profile, then my org) to grab that `Id` and use it for any further updates moving forward.

An example is when I instantiate the `UtilTest.acc` variable somewhere in my `@testSetup` class, I then store the `Id` that's created in your most applicable custom setting level (along with all other created variables, like a Contact `con` and a Lead `l`), which are then recalled from the custom setting in the `@isTest` methods later instead of recreating the variables from scratch (since they are wiped clean between `@isTest` methods).  This avoids noisy DML operations as much as humanly possible!

```
public with sharing class UtilCustomSettings {

    public static TestSettings__c TestSettings {
        get {
            if (TestSettings == null) {
                if (Test.isRunningTest() && TestSettings__c.getInstance().Name == null)
                    UtilTest.buildTestSettings();
                TestSettings = TestSettings__c.getInstance();
            }
            return TestSettings;
        }
        set;
    }

    public static Map<Id, Id> TestSettingsIds {
        get{
            if (TestSettingsIds == null) {
                TestSettingsIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
                for (TestSettings__c setting : [SELECT Id, SetupOwnerId FROM TestSettings__c]) {
                    TestSettingsIds.put(setting.SetupOwnerId, setting.Id);
                }
            }
            return TestSettingsIds;
        }
        set;
    }

    public static void setTestSettingsId() {
        if (TestSettings.Id == null) {
            TestSettings.Id = TestSettingsIds.get(TestSettingsIds.containsKey(UserInfo.getUserId()) ? UserInfo.getUserId() : (TestSettingsIds.containsKey(UserInfo.getProfileId()) ? UserInfo.getProfileId() : UserInfo.getOrganizationId()));
        }
    }

    public static void updateTestSettings(String field, Object value) {
        setTestSettingsId();
        TestSettings__c setting = new TestSettings__c(Id = TestSettings.Id);
        setting.put(field, value);
        update setting;
    }

}
```